# Ampersand & special character on a Active Directory Name and CMD commands

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, special-characters

I have a group that part of its name contains an ampersand & 
I am trying different commands for example dsquery group -name A&I-group but it does not work 
I tried escaping it using the escape character ^ but it still does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not authoritative, but have you tried using quotes around the name?  or ~ as escape?

Comment: Post your query!

Comment: Escaping with a ` character works for me

Comment: @rfportilla I tried using quotes on the entire group and just on the ampersand doesn't work either

Comment: @AthomSfere one of the queries is the one I put in the question dsquer group -name  A&I-group

Comment: You are using double quotes too right?

Comment: Yes, I only used double quotes between the &

Comment: If I just do dsquery group -name A* it list this group but that is not good for my work

Comment: For god sake, the same team sent me the wrong name it worked after finding the correct name after looking it with the query &*

Comment: @Eduardo: In that case since the question is invalid now you might want to delete it.